# Vue 2.0.1 and Electron - Visual Flash

Tags: vue.js, electron

I'm creating an app visually similar to [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com) to manage and search for my bookmarks. Its working well, but when I do a search and open a bookmark, I immediately hide the app and when I invoke it again, it return to the default mode doing a visual flash. The reset to default is triggered right before hiding the app.

I hide the application like this : `remote.app.hide()` and I added a listener on `win.hide` in my components to reset the vue.

It works, but the reset is processed after the application show up again.

I don't know how to do it when the application is hide or to show up it right after the vue is reloaded.

If you have any clue, it would be great.

I created a sample project on Github you can clone and test this issue.

[Github Project](https://github.com/Cronos87/electron-vue-flash-issue)

I'm working on macOS at the moment.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an easy way, you cannot rely on the window.on('hide') event.

So in your shortcut registration, I made your app emit a custom event that your Vue.js will listen to reset your input before hiding the app:

main.js

```
const retShow = globalShortcut.register('CmdOrCtrl+Alt+V', () => {
  if (!win.isVisible()) {
    win.show()
  } else {
    app.emit('hide-window'); // Let the window hide the app
  }
})
```

In your Vue.js app, in the created hook:

app.js

```
app.on('hide-window', function () {
  vm.reset();
  setTimeout(app.hide, 10);
});
```

Here my pull request: https://github.com/Cronos87/electron-vue-flash-issue/pull/1/files